# Why I cant create raw socket in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm learning how to work with raw sockets in Linux. I'm trying to create a socket like that:

```
if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) < 0) {
    perror("socket() failed");
    exit(-1);
}
```

But all I got after launch is:

> socket() failed: Operation not permitted

I know that only root can create raw sockets, but if I run it with SUID bit or sudo - the 
problem is the same. What's wrong? The system is Ubuntu 11.04.

Maybe I'm including needless headers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

And I'm wondering - why SUID is useless?

Comment: interesting; tried to be really root? (and checked privileges are not dropped before executing that line?)

Comment: no, I just call setuid(getuid()); right after the socket creation, but it doesn't even reach that.

Comment: if you do: sudo bash (or sudo whatever-shell-you-use) and then you execute the program...? does it work?

Comment: Hmm, yep, it works in this way. But why suid is useless?

Comment: Have you tried to do **seteuid** -- the setuid bit on the program does not set the effective uid, and that may need to be set programatically.

Comment: I just set suid using chmod u+s

Comment: `suid` doesn't mean `root`. You can google it and study what `suid` is used for. BTW, you can edit your post and add info about `ls -l yourfile`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My money on you not running your code correctly.

I've copied and pasted your exact code into an empty `main()`. I get the same error if I run it as myself, but it runs correctly under `sudo`. This is on Ubuntu.

The code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{ 
  int sd;
  if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) < 0) {
    perror("socket() failed");
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Run as myself:

```
aix@aix:~$ ./a.out 
socket() failed: Operation not permitted
aix@aix:~$
```

Run as root:

```
aix@aix:~$ sudo ./a.out 
aix@aix:~$
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly, too. But my code differs from yours only by the headers. I've included all that stuff (added in question).

Comment: what sudoers can do for real is configurable; is it possible ubuntu 11 default for sudoers is not to give a real root-powered user?

Comment: Saved me a fair bit of time. Much appreciated NPE.

Answer (score 9):

according to man: Only processes with an effective user ID of 0 or the CAP_NET_RAW capability are allowed to open raw sockets

So you could run you application with sudo as was suggested below or set CAP_NET_RAW capability to it (actually you'll need CAP_NET_ADMIN too):

```
# setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip PATH_TO_YOUR_APPLICATION
```

Details could be found at http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/linux-privs/kernel-2.4/capfaq-0.2.txt

Answer (score 0):

Header will not affect it in anyway.

Even if you would be adding some more unnecessary files it will not affect the working of the program.