# C Socket Bind Failed with the Error: Operation not permitted

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I am writing a server-client program. My program creates the socket successfully, but when it tries to bind it, it generates error shows that the bind was not successful.

The error message is:

> Faild to bind - in main: Operation not permitted

So what possibly went wrong? Is it the sockaddr_un struct? This is part of the code, I won't display all the code because I am getting many flags for that! So if additional code is needed please let me know.

```
//server log socket
struct sockaddr_un server = {AF_UNIX, "log_server"};
sl = socket (AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sl < 0) {
perror("Faild to create socket - in main");
    exit(1);
}
bn = bind (sl, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
if(bn < 0){
    perror("Faild to bind - in main");
    exit(1);
}
lis = listen (sl, 1); //to be changed to 4
if (lis < 0) {
    perror("Faild to listen - in main");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this is useful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178970/sockets-on-ubuntu-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: @GAVD Yup even though the link you gave me is for C++ but it seems working with sockets are kind of the same thing. My problem was that was trying to run the file on linux (in virtual machine) and the file is from a mounted folder on my original mac.