# socket:Operation Not permitted

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, networking

I am trying to define an AF_PACKET socket in my program, in order to create a packet sniffer. I get a permission error when running the program.

```
#define SOCK_PATH "/home/username/Desktop/PacketSniffer"
int main()
{
   int fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
   if (fd == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
   }
   printf("Hello World!")
   return 0
}
```

The error is simply

```
socket: operation not permitted
```

I added the define statement as per the answer of this question: [Sockets on Ubuntu (operation not permitted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178970/sockets-on-ubuntu-operation-not-permitted)
but the problem still persists.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: From the [raw manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html): *EPERM,  The user doesn't have permission to open raw sockets.
              Only processes with an effective user ID of 0 or the
              CAP_NET_RAW attribute may do that.* So run the program as root or set that capability

Comment: The define statements does nothing in your code - it is unused. in the thread you referenced it is used in a `AF_UNIX` socket, not a `AF_PACKET` socket - so that is redundant. as @kaylum said - the runnin user needs to have `CAP_NET_RAW`